# Rebuilding object files when a header changes

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following rules in my Makefile:

```
%.o:        $(HFILES)

%.o:        %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $*.c
```

where `HFILES` contains all headers of my project.

The Problem is that this does not rebuild the object files when a header changes as intended.  Why does the first line not add the headers to the prerequisites of the object files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's not how pattern rules work.  The documentation for pattern rules says that when you create a pattern rule with no recipe that *cancels* the pattern rule (that is, deletes it).

Since your first line is creating a pattern rule with a target `%.o` and prerequisites `$(HFILES)` but no recipe, that line simply cancels a pattern rule (which doesn't exist anyway).

You can write:

```
%.o: %.c $(HFILES)
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

(you shouldn't put the `-c` flag in your `CFLAGS` variable).

Be aware that, of course, this means that if ANY header file in `HFILES` changes, *ALL* `.o` files that use this pattern will be rebuilt.