# CMake: How to automatically rebuild .obj-files when included header changed

Tags: c++, cmake, header-files

From my own search, I'm not exactly sure what the "normal" behaviour is:
Does CMake normally rebuild .obj-files when a header included in the associated source file changes?
Because it doesn't do that in my project at all. Here's my top-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15 FATAL_ERROR)

enable_language(CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# project and binary name
project("myProjectName")


# compiler specific warnings
# and warnings are treated as errors
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU" OR
    "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
    set(warnings "-Wall -Wextra -Werror")
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
    set(warnings "/W4 /WX /EHsc")
endif()
if (NOT CONFIGURED_ONCE)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${warnings}"
        CACHE STRING "Flags used by the compiler during all build types." FORCE)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS   "${warnings}"
        CACHE STRING "Flags used by the compiler during all build types." FORCE)
endif()

# default build-type is Debug:

if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
endif()


# =============================
# libraries
# =============================

# external
# eigen numerics library
find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
set( EIGEN Eigen3::Eigen )

# some internal libraries here
set( LIB_NAME_1 lib1 )
set( LIB_NAME_2 lib2 )


# =============================
# directory configuration
# =============================

# for finding libraries and such in the project's subdirectories
# all paths are prepended with the project's root directory
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

# specifiying output directories 
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
#set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
# the last one is disabled to allow for tests in a different directory

# include paths
include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib # I put header-only libraries there
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src # for template definitions
)


# =============================
# unit test configuration
# =============================
# enable_testing() sets the internal flag "CMAKE_TESTING_ENABLED" to 1
# add_test() commands are only run when enable_testing() has executed.
# here, it is only executed in debug mode
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    enable_testing()
endif()


# the unit test framework used here is "Catch2" (single header file "catch.hpp")
# (https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2)

if ( ${CMAKE_TESTING_ENABLED} )
    message( "-- Tests are enabled" )
    set( UNIT_TEST_LIB catch2 )
endif()


# =============================
# subdir calls
# =============================
# the second parameter specifies the output path for binaries.
# however, the respective CMAKE_XYZ_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY takes precedence
add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(src bin)

if ( ${CMAKE_TESTING_ENABLED} )
    add_subdirectory(tests tests)
endif()
```

and then I have another CMakeLists.txt in lib, src and tests. These contain only `addLibrary`, `addExecutable` and `targetLinkLibraries` commands using the appropriate source files. Except in "tests", where there's also `addTest` and `addCustomCommand` to make the unit test executable run after building.

Here's the question: Did I miss something and it should be rebuilding when a header changes (1)? Or is this the normal behaviour (2)?

Possibly related questions:

[Rebuilding object files when a header changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950455/rebuilding-object-files-when-a-header-changes)

[Make doesn't rebuild headers when changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637762/make-doesnt-rebuild-headers-when-changed)

[GCC included header (using `-include`) changes not detected by CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52685787/gcc-included-header-using-include-changes-not-detected-by-cmake)

Comment: Only if the headers are added to that target along with the source files. In your case in the subdirs `lib/src/tests`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake does rebuild object files when headers change, however CMake 3.15 had a bug where it didn't work properly for make targets. I encountered that issue too, and found that it was already reported: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19507

It's fixed in 3.15.1, so the solution is to upgrade (and maybe change the cmake_minimum_required to 3.15.1).